# Fixed effects regression for unbalanced panel data (sample size, interaction term, statistical significance)

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interaction, sample-size, fixed-effects-model

I have a highly unbalanced panel data set (n= 70 firms, T= 5-3000 observations per firm, N= 15000 observations overall). I specified a fixed effect regression with time and entity fixed effects. I have one main regressor variable, one interaction term, three control variables and the rest are dummies added by the time and entity fixed effects resulting in 58 regressors.

I have the following questions regarding the model specification:

1. Is the highly unbalanced data a problem?
2. Is the sample size of 15000 enough in this case?

Further I have some questions regarding the **interaction term**
(please consider these scenarios separately, not as happening at
once):

4. The coefficient of the main regressor becomes larger after adding
   the interaction term even though the interaction is not significant,
   but the model fit (R2) stays the same. What might be the reason for
   this?
5. The main regressor is not significant, but the second
   regressor and the interaction effect are, however with a very small
   coefficient. How to interpret/report such a result?
6. The coefficient
   of the main regressor is positive and significant, the interaction
   term negative. This would mean that the larger the second regressor
   (X2), the smaller the effect of the main regressor (X1), right?

I would appreciate any help, including source suggestions that might help to clear up my confusion.